# Remove matte(alpha bleed) after combining jpg and alpha to get png image in iOS

Tags: ios, png, quartz-graphics, alpha, jpeg

To reduce the size of the application, I use jpg and alpha over png image. I am able to merge jpg and alpha image to get png but the issue is that it is leaving an alpha bleed(matte) where the edges are little sharp. Please help me with this.

Below code which I have written helps me to get png image from jpg and alpha image. Please help me to get rid of alpha bleed(matte). Thanks.

```
+ (UIImage*)pngImageWithJPEG:(UIImage*)jpegImage compressedAlphaFile:(UIImage*)alphaImage
{
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, jpegImage.size.width, jpegImage.size.height);

//Pixel Buffer
uint32_t* piPixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(imageRect.size.width * imageRect.size.height * sizeof(uint32_t));

memset(piPixels, 0, imageRect.size.width * imageRect.size.height * sizeof(uint32_t));

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(piPixels, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height, 8, sizeof(uint32_t) * imageRect.size.width, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

//Drawing the alphaImage to the pixel buffer to seperate the alpha values
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, alphaImage.CGImage);

//Buffer to store the alpha values from the alphaImage
uint8_t* piAlpha = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * imageRect.size.width * imageRect.size.height);

//Copying the alpha values from the alphaImage to the alpha buffer
for (uint32_t y = 0; y < imageRect.size.height; y++) 
{
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < imageRect.size.width; x++)
    {
        uint8_t* piRGBAPixel = (uint8_t*)&piPixels[y * (uint32_t)imageRect.size.width + x];

        //alpha = 0, red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3.
        piAlpha[y * (uint32_t)imageRect.size.width + x] = piRGBAPixel[1];
    }
}

//Drawing the jpegImage in the pixel buffer.
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, jpegImage.CGImage);

//Setting alpha to the jpegImage
for (uint32_t y = 0; y < imageRect.size.height; y++) 
{
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < imageRect.size.width; x++)
    {
        uint8_t* piRGBAPixel = (uint8_t*)&piPixels[y * (uint32_t)imageRect.size.width + x];

        float fAlpha0To1 = piAlpha[y * (uint32_t)imageRect.size.width + x] / 255.0f;

        //alpha = 0, red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3.
        piRGBAPixel[0] = piAlpha[y * (uint32_t)imageRect.size.width + x];
        piRGBAPixel[1] *= fAlpha0To1;
        piRGBAPixel[2] *= fAlpha0To1;
        piRGBAPixel[3] *= fAlpha0To1;
    }
}

//Creating image from the pixel buffer
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

//Releasing resources
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
free(piPixels);
free(piAlpha);

//Creating the pngImage to return from the cgImage
UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

//Releasing the cgImage.
CGImageRelease(cgImage);

return pngImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Premultiplied alpha colorspace handles color bleed much better. Try pre-processing source pixels like this:

```
r = r*a;
g = g*a;
b = b*a;
```

To get orignal values you'd usually reverse this after you read the image (divide RGB values by `a` if `a` > 0), but since iOS works in premultiplied alpha color natively, you don't even have to do that.

---

Also try [PNG8+Alpha](http://pngquant.org) format, which sometimes may be smaller than separate JPG+mask.